# GitLab CI Pipeline use Tag-name in deploy-path

Tags: .net-core, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have the following GitLab CI file:

```yaml
image : mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0

stages:
  - build
  - test
  - release

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - dotnet build

test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - dotnet test

release:
  stage: release
  only:
    - tags
  except:
    - branches
    - develop
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - publish/
  script:
    - dotnet publish -c Release --no-self-contained -o \\\\my\\path\\my-project-{{tag-name}} WebService/WebService.csproj
```

Now I want to get the "Tag-Name" in the path where the project has to get deployed to.
Is that possible and when, how can I archive this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [predefined variable](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html) `$CI_COMMIT_TAG` to achieve this.

This variable will contain the name of the tag, **if** a tag is set; otherwise, it will evaluate to an empty string. Since your job only runs on tags, the variable will be set.

```
release:
  stage: test 
  only:
    - tags
  except:
    - branches
    - develop
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - publish/
  script:
    - dotnet publish -c Release --no-self-contained -o \\\\my\\path\\my-project-${CI_COMMIT_TAG} WebService/WebService.csproj
```